# Styling Bootstrap2.3.2 modal doesn´t work

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I need to change the opacity of a modal-backdrop div that pop-ups when a bootstrap modal window is opened.

According to the css looks pretty easy. Overwriting

```
.modal-backdrop, .modal-backdrop .fade .in{opacity: .3 !important}
```

should be enough. However, when I do it, the modal doesn´t show anymore.

Please see this plunker: https://plnkr.co/edit/I6BSKbpclDnBNunNwLt2?p=preview

Note: If you delete the css line, you can see it works.

Answer (score 1):

The !important has to be removed. Then works!

```
.modal-backdrop, .modal-backdrop .fade .in{opacity: .3}
```